# Which site-lisp file was loaded, default.el or default.elc?

Tags: byte-compilation, site-lisp

I'm setting up some site-wide default configuration in the site-lisp directory, and trying to figure out whether emacs is loading the byte-compiled `default.elc` or `default.el`. I haven't applied any other configuration, such as `load-prefer-newer`.

With the following `default.el`

```
(defvar foo nil)
```

and having compiled it so both the .el and .elc files are present, if I run `describe-symbol` on `foo` I'm shown:

> foo is a variable defined in 'default.el'

and the `*Messages*` buffer shows the path to `default.el` (as if it loaded it to look up the symbol, though I don't know if that's actually what it means).

If I remove the .el file leaving only the .elc file, then start emacs and again describe `foo` it shows:

> foo is a variable defined in 'default.elc'

and in the `*Messages*` buffer I see the path to `default.elc`.

I had expected it to load the byte-compiled .elc file when both were present, but can't tell if that's what's happening. How can I check?

Comment: One option is to inspect or save the value of `load-file-name` in `default.el`, which will give you the name of the file that was actually loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h v load-history`

Then search the variable value (in buffer `*Help*`) for the library you're interested in, e.g. `default.el` or `default.elc`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It was indeed loading the .elc file, which is what I was hoping for.